# Percentile aggregation in Timelion

Tags: kibana, kibana-6, timelion

I'm trying to change a Timelion query from averages to percentiles. My current, working query is `.es(index=*, metric='avg:duration')`. This gives me a nice graph.

Now I change my query to `.es(index=*, metric='percentiles:duration:50,95')` as documented [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/15154). Kibana doesn't give an error, but also doesn't show any graph.

The `duration` field is properly marked as type number and aggregatable, so I think it should be fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Note that the `percentiles` aggregation was only added in 6.2.0, but earlier versions do accept the name without actually giving an error.